# SQL Search in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms

I'm trying to setup a simple C# form to search one of our SQL databases.  I keep getting a 'SQLException was Unhandled' error when I try to debug.  I know the SQL statement works, I can run it just fine on my server.  I think it's a problem with the way that I am trying to input the data from the `TextBox`. Can someone give me some guidance?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace USER_Lookup
{
    public partial class Search : Form
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PC01; Initial Catalog=DB01; Integrated Security=TRUE");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        public Search()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
                    }

        private void button_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string badgeCode = textBox_badgeCode.Text.Trim();
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand
                ("SELECT db01.dbo.staff.lastname AS 'Last Name', db01.dbo.staff.firstname AS 'First Name', db01.dbo.staff.badgecode AS 'User ID', db01.dbo.staffrole.name AS 'Role' FROM db01.dbo.staff, db01.dbo.staffrole, db01.dbo.staff_staffrole WHERE db01.dbo.staff.badgecode =" + badgeCode + "AND db01.dbo.staff.id = db01.dbo.staff_staffrole.staff_id AND db01.dbo.staff_staffrole.staffrole_id = db01.dbo.staffrole.id", cs);
            ds.Clear();
            da.Fill(ds);

            dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to sanitize your input and learn about SQL Injection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No space here

```
... db01.dbo.staff.badgecode =" + badgeCode + "AND db01.dbo.staff.id ....
                                              ^^^^
```

Also here you use `maclive.dbo.staff.lastname` but there is no FROM or JOIN for this database
(typo?)

And, if `db01.dbo.staff.badgecode` is a varchar field then you need single quotes around your badgeCode variable. However, string concatenation to form a SQL command is the sure path to [Sql Injection attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)
Change your code to use parameters

```
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand 
    ("SELECT maclive.dbo.staff.lastname AS 'Last Name', " + 
     "db01.dbo.staff.firstname AS 'First Name', db01.dbo.staff.badgecode AS 'User ID',  "+ 
     "db01.dbo.staffrole.name AS 'Role' " + 
     "FROM db01.dbo.staff, db01.dbo.staffrole, db01.dbo.staff_staffrole " + 
     "WHERE db01.dbo.staff.badgecode =@badge AND db01.dbo.staff.id = " + 
     "db01.dbo.staff_staffrole.staff_id AND db01.dbo.staff_staffrole.staffrole_id = " + 
     "db01.dbo.staffrole.id", cs);

da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@badge", badgecode);
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you so much for your help.  I have heard about sql injection attacks but I am pretty knew to sql so I don't know much about them so it's time to do some more reading!  This is perfect.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need single quotes around badgeCode. Also, you're missing a space before the next *AND*. Try this:

```
...staff.badgecode = '" + badgeCode + "' AND...
```

Please bear in mind that your code contains an SQL Injection Attack vulnerability. You should use parameters to supply the badgeCode.